# Regex to match word, followed by zero or more digits?

Tags: java, regex

I need a regular expression to match line beginning with a specific `WORD`, followed by zero or more digits, then nothing more. So far I've tried this:

```
^WORD\d{0,}
```

and this:

```
^WORD[0-9]*
```

But it doesn't work as expected: it is also matching lines like `WORD11a`, which I don't want.

Comment: Define "doesn't work as expected". What matches that shouldn't? What doesn't match that should?

Comment: It seems correct, given the information you have provided. Describe how it fails.

Answer (score 3):

I forgot the `$` end of line character, so it matched:

```
WORD1
WORD11
WORD11a
```

this works, just fine:

```
^WORD\\d*$
```

Comment: Depends on how you use it I suppose. It doesn't seem to work in [this case](http://ideone.com/7lfLN).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably that `^` matches the beginning of the input (I suspect you only find a match if the first line matches), and not the beginning of a line.

You could try using a positive lookbehind saying that the match should be preceded by either start of input (`^`) or a new line (`\n`):

```
String input = "hello156\n"+
               "world\n" +
               "hello\n" +
               "hell55\n";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=^|\n)hello\\d*");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
while (m.find())
    System.out.println("\"" + m.group() + "\"");
```

Prints:

```
"hello156"
"hello"
```

Answer (score 0):

"(\\AWORD[\\d]*$)"
this should do the trick. beginning of input, your WORD, and a number